# How to replicate column default value from DB2 to Oracle

Tags: oracle, db2, default-value

I am trying to see if it is possible to replicate a behavior from DB2 over to Oracle which has to do with setting default values on a table's column.

In DB2:

```
.
.
mychar    CHAR(8)  NOT NULL                     
        WITH DEFAULT SESSION_USER,
.
.
```

I understand how to do things in oracle like setting the default value to a specific string, but I'm not sure if there is an Oracle equivalent to DB2 allowing you have the `SESSION_USER` be the default value.

Do I need to get creative with maybe triggers and stored procedures? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works the same in Oracle.

The Oracle syntax is almost the same. You don't use the keyword `WITH` in Oracle, only the keyword `DEFAULT`. And the user in Oracle is `USER` rather than `SESSION_USER`.

Comment: In fact, the same syntax `myfield char(8) not null default user` is also valid in DB2, at least in the `DB2 for i` variant.